# How to implement kfold cross validation in hmmlearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, hmmlearn, k-fold

The [hmmlearn tutorial](http://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#building-hmm-and-generating-samples) demonstrates how a Hidden Markov Model can be fitted to a dataset:

```
model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3, covariance_type="full", n_iter=100)
model.fit(X)
```

Is there a built-in way to do cross validation, Or do I have to do it by hand?

Comment: interesting, I assumed I could plug that model into sklearn's cross_val_score but apparently not

Comment: I was hoping too, that the hmmlearn model would integrate into the sklearn environment like that...

Comment: You mean 'built-in' in `hmmlearn` package, not `sklearn`? Or are you asking why `sklearn`'s cross-validation methods don't work with hmmlearn? (what happens if you try them? show your code and/or errors please. cc: @MaxPower) OP please clarify your question, it's too broad/unclear.